# Non Relational Database , Key Value or flat table

Tags: gwt, nosql, datastore

My application needs configurable columns , and titles of these columns get configured in the begining, If relation database I would have created generic columns in table like CodeA, CodeB etc for this need because it helps queering  on these columns (Code A = 11 ) it also helps in displaying the values (if that columns stores code and value) but now I am using Non Relational database Datastore (and I am new to it), should I follow the same old approach or I should use collection (Key Value pair) type of structure .

There will be lot of filters on these columns. Please suggest

Comment: NoSQL doesn't have the querying capability of an SQL. Why are you choosing a NoSQL here? When you say configurable columns what does it mean? Please explain.

Comment: I am using Google Apps and datastore is the only available database. Configurable columns mean, say i say my record can have ten dimensions , but when i create instance i define which dimension means what... like in account system, some may want to configure product as one dimension and other client may like Project at the place of Product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've just described is one of the classic scenarios for a Key-Value database. The limitation here is that you will not have many of the set-based tools you're used to.

Most of the K-V databases are really good at loading one "record" or small set thereof. However, they don't tend to be any good at loading anything that may require a join. Given that you're using AppEngine, you probably appreciate this limitation. But it's worth stating.

As an important note, not all K-V database will allow you to "select by any column". Many K-V stores actually only allow for selection by a primary key. If you take a look at MongoDB, you'll find that you can query any column which sounds like a necessary feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using key/value pairs where keys will act as your column names and value will be their data.